# ClasscastException in LauncherActivity

Tags: android

i am getting ClasscastException when launching my app the problem is in  TaxiTwinApplication app = (TaxiTwinApplication)getApplication(); this is the Activity A which i am trying to call method from other class

public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Intent intent;
    TaxiTwinApplication app = (TaxiTwinApplication)getApplication();
    app.register();
    switch (TaxiTwinApplication.getUserState()) {
        case NOT_SUBSCRIBED:
        case SUBSCRIBED:
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            break;
        case PARTICIPANT:
            intent = new Intent(this, MyTaxiTwinActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            break;
        case OWNER:
            intent = new Intent(this, MyTaxiTwinActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            break;
        default:
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

public class TaxiTwinApplication extends Application {

```
private static int pendingNotificationsCount = 0;
private static UserState userState = NOT_SUBSCRIBED;
private ServicesManagement servicesManagement;
private LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public void unregister() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

public void register() {
    servicesManagement = new ServicesManagement(this);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationUpdate(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 3, this);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
    //every 10 seconds and at least 3 meters
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 3, locationListener);
}

private void locationUpdate(Location location) {
    GcmHandler gcmHandler = new GcmHandler(this);
    gcmHandler.locationChanged(location);
}

public static int getPendingNotificationsCount() {
    return pendingNotificationsCount;
}

public static void setPendingNotificationsCount(int pendingNotifications) {
    pendingNotificationsCount = pendingNotifications;
}

public static UserState getUserState() {
    return userState;
}

public static void setUserState(UserState userState) {
    TaxiTwinApplication.userState = userState;
}

public static void exit(Context context) {
    GcmHandler gcmHandler = new GcmHandler(context);
    if (userState == UserState.OWNER || userState == UserState.PARTICIPANT) {
        gcmHandler.leaveTaxiTwin();
    }
    gcmHandler.unsubscribe();

    TaxiTwinApplication app = (TaxiTwinApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    app.unregister();

    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    dbHelper.deleteTables(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase());
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

}

Comment: have you declared `android:name=".TaxiTwinApplication"` in your `<application>` tag in your manifest?

Comment: No sir i did'nt actually i am new in app development so i don't know about that i'll try now

Comment: Element application is not allowed here  when using <application> tag in manifest

Comment: Your formatting is wrong - see example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-android-sources-androidmanifest-xml.html - it needs to be xml attribute.

Comment: sorry i dont understand you but i tried to declare it inside application in activty tag and meta ta but it did'nt work

Answer (score 0):

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com....TaxiTwinApplication">
```